# Changing Attribute with Javascript-Header Problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following HTML displays a fancy font on my site, due some alterations I made to `<h2>`

```
<section id="content">
    <article>
        <h2 id="titletext">Welcome to <span>Pomona High School!</span></h2>
        <p id="infotext" style="width: 773px; height: 28px;" >Welcome to the new Pomona High School site! Please give us feedback!</p>
        <br />
    </article>
</section>​
```

This displays quite fine in the site.

[image: Fancy Header 2 Font]

When the user now goes to the taskbar and chooses one of the submenu items, the `<h2>` text will change to a specified string value. I went into the Javascript editor and produced the following.

```
window.onhashchange = function() { //when the hash changes (the '#' part)
    var loc = window.location + ""; //get the current location (from the address bar)
    var curHash = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf("#")); //get what's after the '#'
    if (curHash == "#mission") { //else if it's #mission
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Mission Statement';
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Pomona High School';

    }
};​
```

Linking one of the menu items to #mission, I was succesful in changing the text. But the font changed to the default `<h2>` font.

I need help on how to bring my custom font onto strings in Javascript. Thanks in advance!

CSS stylsheet for `<h2>`:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #212222;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

h2 span {
    color: #8a8a8a;
}
```

And here's the two custom font files (too big to copy and paste to Stack Overflow):-

- [Regular Font](http://www.2shared.com/document/ei1M_wuV/Humanst521_Lt_BT_400font.html)
- [Light Font](http://www.2shared.com/document/iZmz54Wn/Humanst521_BT_400font.html)

Comment: `else if(curHash == "#mission")`: else not needed?.. An what exactly happens? Maybe you are just missing the `<span>` in the `titletext` element?

Comment: sorry, I was trimming some unecessary code. There was actaully if (curHash== "#home") at the top but that was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Source:** [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange)

Here's what MDN has to say about this:

> The hashchange event fires when a window's hash changes (see
>   location.hash).
>
> **Syntax:-**
>
> - `window.onhashchange = funcRef;`
> - `<body onhashchange="funcRef();">`
> - `window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);`

I *think* that passing `function() { ... }` is a function reference but could you try defining the function first and then passing a named reference? The code would go:

```
function hashChange() { //when the hash changes (the '#' part)
    var loc = window.location + ""; //get the current location (from the address bar)
    var curHash = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf("#")); //get what's after the '#'
    if (curHash == "#mission") { //else if it's #mission
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Mission Statement';
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Pomona High School';

    }
};

window.onhashchange = hashChange;
```

​

---

OK, I'm confused. There must be something else going on as it's working for me in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YatharthROCK/KfAFE/)...

---

Your code removes the `<span>` in the `<h2>` on hash change which was presumably giving the styling. So it should really be:

```
window.onhashchange = function() { //when the hash changes (the '#' part)
    var loc = window.location + ""; //get the current location (from the address bar)
    var curHash = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf("#")); //get what's after the '#'

    if (curHash == "#mission") { //else if it's #mission
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = '<span>Mission Statement</span>';
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Welcome to <span>Pomona High School</span>';
    }​
}
```

---

Also, I think you're mixing up the `if` and `else` statements. This:

```
else if(curHash == "#mission") {
    ...
}

else {
    ...
}
```

should really be:

```
if(curHash == "#mission") {
    ...
}

else if {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The code changes the the text to white, but it still does not dsiplay the custom font. My custom font is shown when a string has the <h2> tag, not the <span> tag, keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @parion Can you provide us with your CSS also?

Comment: What parts of the stylesheet would you wish to see?

Comment: @parion Anything pertaining to the h2 elements or anything else relevant. Just dump everything here if you're too lazy, someone will edit it.

Comment: Added it. The real code is js/Humanst521_BT_400.font.js, but the file is way too big to add on Stack Overflow. Makes no sense either. xD

Comment: @parion Outta ideas. Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YatharthROCK/KfAFE/), it works for me there...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18367/discussion-between-parion-and-yatharthrock)

Comment: @parion Link us to the exact place where you notice this problem happening. That might help...

Comment: I did. The picture is what it looks like with the custom font. When running the Javascript, the text will change to the default h2 font.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually replacing

```
Welcome to <span>Pomona High School!</span>
```

with

```
Welcome to Pomona High School!
```

Notice, no  element. Just set it with the span tag, and you will be fine.

Comment: The <span> tag is actually used to change the font's color from black to white. <h2>Welcome to Pomona High School</h2> will display the custom font .

Comment: You can see the <span> tag in action in the HTML code I provided at the top of the page.

Comment: I actually can't :-) Try this instead: `document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Welcome to <span>Pomona High School!</span>';`

Comment: Ok, then your problem is not with the code you pasted here. You probably change some css elsewhere in the code. Try inspecting your html/css in firebug.